# Explanation for some parts of this proof.

Tags: ring-theory, gcd-and-lcm, unique-factorization-domains

**We want to prove that in a UFD the gcd exists.**

In the proof we let $R$ be a UFD and $a,b \in R$
So we suppose that $a,b$ are not units because if one of them were the unit, the proof is trivial.

The proof now let $a,b$ be both non units.
Well we know that we can write $$a=T_1×...×T_m$$ and $$b=R_1×....×R_m$$ were $T_i$ and $R_j$ are irreducible elements.
Now we can rewrite them as $$a=p_1^{α_1}.....p_n^{α_n}$$
And $$b=p_1^{β_1}....p_n^{β_n}$$ were $p_i$ are prime obviously.
Here's my 1st question: how did we let the prime elements in both $a$ and $b$ be equal and with same index $n$?? Shouldn't they be different? Shouldn't we say that $b=q_1^{β_1}...q_m^{β_m}$??

Also:
it defines $s_i=min(α_i,β_i)$ and let $d=p_1^{s_1}...p_n^{s_n}$. again how are the primes equals to the case of $a$ and $b$?
The proof proceeded to show that $d$ is the gcd.
I can see why $d$ is the common divisor.
To show that d is the gcd, we let $x|a$ and $x|b$
Then if x is a unit then $x|d$
But what if x is non unit??

The proof needs details that the author didn't include or they're trivial but I don't see them.
Please help! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that we allow the exponents $\alpha_i,\beta_i$ to be zero, and the list $p_1,\dots,p_n$ contains all primes that divide *either $a$ or $b$*.

The other important thing is that in an UFD, $a\,|\,b$ iff for every prime $p$ and exponent $\gamma\in\Bbb N$ we have $p^\gamma\,|\,a\implies p^\gamma\,|\,b$, that is, for every prime $p$, if the exponent of $p$ in $a$ is $\alpha$ and in $b$ is $\beta$ (and a priori they can be zero as well), then $\alpha\le\beta$.

Comment: Suppose $x=\prod_iq_i^{\gamma_i}$ with $q_i$ irreducible with $x|a$ and $x|b$, then $\gamma_i>0$ implies that $q_i$ divides both $a$ and $b$, so it's among the $p_j$'s and $\gamma_i\le \alpha_i$ as well as $\le\beta_i$.

Comment: Yes, I figured out the last part. Sorry I deleted the comment before you replied. Thank you very much!